# Macro has stopped working after making no changes - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I cobbled together with my somewhat rudimentary VBA knowledge from a few different sources that's been working for a few years without issue. All of a sudden, it's stopped functioning properly. I haven't made any changes, and I can't determine what the issue is from the error message I get. I'd be very appreciative if someone could take a look and tell me why I'm receiving an error.

I download a report from the web and then open it in Excel. The first time the macro runs it changes the sheet names and then runs some more steps; any additional times, the sheets are already named so it continues on.

This is the beginning of the code; I'll note where I receive the error below. The error code is *Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range*.

```
If ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet1" Or ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet2" Or ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet3" Then
    
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Range("A:L").Select
    Selection.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

ElseIf ActiveSheet.name <> "Sheet1" Or ActiveSheet.name <> "Sheet2" Or ActiveSheet.name <> "Sheet3" Then

    ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet1"
           
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xSht As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    xName = "Sheet2"
    
    If xName = "" Then Exit Sub
        
    Set xSht = Sheets(xName) '<---------  Run-time error "9":Subscript out of range
        
    If Not xSht Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Sheet cannot be created as there is already a worksheet with the same name in this workbook"
        Exit Sub

    End If
            
    Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = xName
  
    Dim xName1 As String
    Dim xSht1 As Object
        
    On Error Resume Next
    
    xName1 = "Sheet3"

    If xName1 = "" Then Exit Sub
        
    Set xSht1 = Sheets(xName1)
        
    If Not xSht1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet cannot be created as there is already a worksheet with the same name in this workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = xName1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

Comment: The error means you have no sheet named "Sheet2" in the currently active workbook (which can be or not the workbook with your code)

Answer (score 1):

Sheets is a collection of all sheets in the workbook. Since no workbook was specified, it assumes you are referencing the Active Workbook. Sheets(*index*) is a method used to access a specific member of the collection.

If no member exists that matches the given name, it returns the error that you've encountered. Which is to say, the active workbook at the time of execution did not contain a sheet with the name "Sheet2".

If you want to test if a sheet exists prior accessing it, wrap it with an error statement like:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set xSht = Sheets(xName)
If Not xSht Is Nothing Then
...
End If
On Error Goto 0
```